# How would I format my background so it registers and logs a user , and I can re-use it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I want to create a background step in my cucumber feature's, so I just register a new user, and log the user in, and then I can just run my scenerios for users who are logged in.

I want to then re-use this on many other features and scenerios.

Any tips?

How should I word it?

```
Given I am a user who registers
And then logs in
```

Like that?

Answer (score 2):

I normally write that as...

```
Given I am logged in as a "<RoleTitle>"
```

`RoleTitle` could of course be something else.

The step will kind of look like

```
Given /^I am logged in as a "([^"]*)"$/ do |role|
  # either run actual steps to register
  # OR
  # use pickle/factories to setup user accounts, if
  # bypassing the registration forms are possible

  # Once created I will (try to) create a pickle reference
  find_model! %{user: "#{role}"}, {:id => User.last.id} # change approach if you need multiple users

  # then log the user in
end
```

Comment: I actually have users setup via my seeds.rb file, how should I reference them to login?  I'm trying to avoid having to hard code the username and pwd.

Comment: I normally don't use my seeds in my tests. But if you must, you can always run the seed, then find the user based on say their email or title or etc... and then use them in your tests.

Comment: do you have to use a session when doing a loggin?  i.e. session.visit("/users/login") session.fill_in("...") etc?

Comment: Cucumber will usually work out all the session stuff if you use the actual login form to login.

Answer (score 0):

Is the actual registration important to your test? Or just the existence of the user?

In our tests we have:

```
When I am logged in as an administrator #or whatever type of user you want
```

and this step will go and create an admin if one doesn't exist already.

Comment: but  you have to go through the login process right?  does it re-create the test db each time?

Comment: Only after each scenario, I believe...we actually have some scenarios where it's key that we log in one type of user, try something, log a second type of user in and try the thing again. But my understanding is that between scenarios the db is blown away and reseeded, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the email address or other attribute of the user, go with something like:

```
Given I am signed in
```

If you need to set some of their data, use Factory Girl and go with something like:

```
Given the following user exists:
  | email             | name       |
  | mark@example.com  | Mark Twain |
And I sign in as "mark@example.com"
```

Info on Factory Girl step definitions:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/284805810/gimme-three-steps

Ideas for writing authentication step definitions:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/blob/master/features/step_definitions/engine/clearance_steps.rb